# How to automate google sheet importHTML trigger from 11-3 every day except friday and saturday and the data should remain as it was in 3pm everyday.?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**This code refresh my data every minute using trigger but I need (11am-3pm) except friday and saturday and then the data should remain in their own place as it was at 3pm till 11am the next morning. Here's my script. What code should i add now to get as required?**

```
 function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getRange("L4");
    var refresh = parseInt(cell.getValue().toString());
    var increment = refresh + 1;
    cell.setValue(increment);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a test like this one (may be you will have to adjust parameters according to you locale)

```
function testDate(){
  d=new Date()
  if (d.getDay()!=5 && d.getDay()!=6 && d.getHours()>=11 && d.getHours()<15) {return true}else{return false}
}
```

and then

```
function myFunction() {if (testDate()==true) {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var cell = sheet.getRange("L4");
    var refresh = parseInt(cell.getValue().toString());
    var increment = refresh + 1;
    cell.setValue(increment);
    }}
```